# Static members in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am tring to emulate static members in javascript.

consider this code:

```
 // option A for static members:

     // constructor...
  function Person(name) {

      this.firstName=name;        
  }

  Person.count=0;              //  like a static member...
  var p=new Person("Dan");
  Person.count++;

  alert(Person.count);   // 1;
```

and now this one:

```
  //  option B for static members:
          // constructor..
  function Person(name) {

      this.firstName=name;
      Person.prototype.count++;     

  }

  Person.prototype.count=0;        //  like a static member...
  var p=new Person("Dan");
  alert(Person.prototype.count);   // 1;

  //       ...
```

so, is it true to say that the main difference between those two, is that in the second example you can refer to the static member from the constuctor (due to the **prototype** decleration), while in the first example you can't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples you can get to it from within the constructor. The difference is in whether you can get to it through one of your objects.

**Option A:**

```
function Person (name) {
    this.firstName = name;
    Person.count++;
}

Person.count = 0;
var p = new Person("Dan")

console.log(Person.count) // 1
console.log(p.count) // undefined
```

**Option B:**

```
function Person (name) {
    this.firstName=name;
    Person.prototype.count++;     
}

Person.prototype.count = 0;
var p = new Person("Dan");

console.log(Person.prototype.count) // 1
console.log(p.count) // 1
```

Comment: @yoavbarnea - I'd think option A is better.

Comment: @yoavbarnea option B is not really a static member, it is an instance member. It just happens that with JS, you can call instance members by accessing them on the prototype