# Does anyone know of a robust JavaScript pseudoclass class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope, pseudo-class, overloading

I'm looking for a relatively simple but efficient mechanism to implement clean looking:

- public, private and protected members (with actual public/private/protected access, but still extensible)
- inheritance (single or multiple)
- constructor overloading (prefer not to have to count args and check types with a complex set of nested conditionals)

Comment: @Xymostech - you can implement an equivalent to "private" with local variables in a closure.

Comment: @nnnnnn Fair point. "protected" is still out, though.

Comment: And javascript does has simple inheritance, something that on a good day can be called overloading, and ways to make variables non accessible. It sounds to me like the OP is looking for some sort of class, like you would have in many C languages, that fixes all this in javascript, and that afaik, does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

All right...made myself a cup of coffee before writing this. Only thing I can't help you with is overloading. But never mind, here we go:

```
// Class pattern with
//    - dynamic prototypes
//    - public, private, static, static private members
// Keeps functions named the way you want it to.
// Working example:
var YourClass = (function(){

    var Pseudo = function(){
        var args = arguments;

        // constuct the instance in here:
        var YourClass = function(){
            var public = this,
                private = {};

            public.foo = args[0] ? args[0] : "bar";
            public.staticPrivateInt = ++static_private.someInt;

            private.fibo = "nacci";

            // fibo is private - return it's value
            // with a getter to make it "protected"
            public.getFibo = function(){
                return private.fibo;
            }

            public.setFibo = function(value){
                if(typeof value === "string"){
                    // handle optional events here
                    return private.fibo = value;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };


        var static = Pseudo,
                 static_private = {};

        // statics:
        static_private.someInt = 100;
        static.increaseSomeInt = function(){
            ++static_private.someInt;
        }


        // extend on creation of an instance:
        YourClass.prototype = args[0] || new Object();  // or anything else, just an example

        return new YourClass;
    };
    return Pseudo;

}());
```

**Usage:**

```
var myInstance = new YourClass({
    someCfg: true
});

console.log(myInstance.someCfg === true); // will log true
```

Thanks to JavaScript's lexical scoping and closures one can indeed **simulate** the way classes are designed in other languages like C++, Java etc.

Keep a few things in mind when using that pattern:

1. Variable names like static, private or public will lead to errors
   when in strict mode. You can rename them if needed.
2. Static private variables should not be stored as `static.private` cause they wouldnt be private anymore (thus the variable `static_private`).

**How it works**

Basically, what you'll want is:

1. `public` members to be accessible with `<object>.<member>`. In Javascript, that is usually done with `this.<member> = <assignment>;`.

   => For convenienve, create a simple alias:
     `var public = this;`
2. `private` members to be visible in the constructor, but not in the instance. Still they need to be accessible for `public` methods.

   => `var private = {};`
      You can create simple variables to, for example `var fibo="nacci";`, I find `private.fibo="nacci";` more readable though. Any variable created with the `var` keyword will not be accessible from the outer scope of the constructor function.
3. `static` members to be ready even if no instance of the class has been created yet. The usual way to do that in JavaScript is assigning a value or function to the constructor itself. See SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420178/static-members-in-javascript)

   => Again, for readability:
      `var static = Pseudo;`
4. `static private` members: Occasionaly, you might want to have static members that are invisible outside your constructor.

   => Use lexical scope to store them. `var static_private = {};`

For further reading on class patterns:

- The *YAHOO module pattern*:
  http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/
- Douglas Crockford (the JS-Hercules) on private members: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html
- [http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+class+pattern&aq=f&oq=javascript+class+pattern](http://www.google.de/search?q=javascript%20class%20pattern&aq=f&oq=javascript%20class%20pattern)